# cursor pointer of select not working because of margin of span

Tags: html, css

```css
 .select span::before {
        content: "\003F";
        display: inline-block;
        font-family: Simple-Line-Icons;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-align: center;
        width: 16px;
        height: 16px;
        font-size: 14px;
        line-height: 12px;
        padding: 1px;
        color: #c4c4c4;
        background: #ffffff;
        border: 2px solid #e8e8e8;
        border-radius: 2px;
        text-decoration: none;
        margin: 0px 0px 2px 260px;
        /* pointer-events: none; */
        -webkit-transition: .25s all ease;
        -o-transition: .25s all ease;
        transition: .25s all ease;
    }
    select {
        cursor: pointer;
       background: #ffffff;
        border: 2px solid #dfdfdf;
        border-radius: 6px;
        width: 287px;
        height: 31px;
        display: block;
        resize: none;
        outline: none;
        color: inherit;
        font-size: inherit;
        font-family: inherit;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
```

```html
<div class="select" style="margin-bottom:60px;">
     <span></span>
    <select name="slct" id="slct" style="margin-top: -26px;">
      <option>Choose an option</option>
      <option value="1">Pure CSS</option>
      <option value="2">No JS</option>
      <option value="3">Nice!</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Hi everyone. I have above code which shows select input element with icon(question mark in box) on right side in it.

The problem is that cursor pointer is not showing all over the select box. However in the middle, its not showing cursor pointer and not clickable. I guess its because of  `margin: 0px 0px 2px 260px;` of  `.select span::before`.

I am not able to figure out the solution. I need that icon which I created on right side in it and select box with icon should show dropdown menu.

How should I do that ? please help me in this.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.select span::before {
    position:relative;
    z-index:1;
        content: "\003F";
        display: inline-block;
        font-family: Simple-Line-Icons;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-align: center;
        width: 16px;
        height: 16px;
        font-size: 14px;
        line-height: 12px;
        padding: 1px;
        color: #c4c4c4;
        background: #ffffff;
        border: 2px solid #e8e8e8;
        border-radius: 2px;
        text-decoration: none;
        margin: 0px 0px 2px 260px;
        pointer-events: none;
        -webkit-transition: .25s all ease;
        -o-transition: .25s all ease;
        transition: .25s all ease;
    }
    select {
    position:relative;
    z-index:0;
        cursor: pointer;
       background: #ffffff;
        border: 2px solid #dfdfdf;
        border-radius: 6px;
        width: 287px;
        height: 31px;
        display: block;
        resize: none;
        outline: none;
        color: inherit;
        font-size: inherit;
        font-family: inherit;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
```

```html
<div class="select" style="margin-bottom:60px;">
     <span></span>
    <select name="slct" id="slct" style="margin-top: -26px;">
      <option>Choose an option</option>
      <option value="1">Pure CSS</option>
      <option value="2">No JS</option>
      <option value="3">Nice!</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: its working, copy the code to your machine and try..plz

Comment: I have edited the answer to be runnable as snippet. Would you please try it just here? @yjs

Comment: Now cursor is not enable all over select? nor the drop down happens....it happens here :o

Comment: @yjs thanks for the answer. I applied it on my page. Cursor pointer is showing in the middle of select but however on my page cursor pointer is not showing on the icon still.

Comment: tried the above code? which browser tried? from your code need to remove this line in css... pointer-events: none;

Comment: Actually on my page code that line `pointer-events: none;` from css was commented. Thats why on my page it was not running and here the code is working. That line should be there. Its working now. Thanks for the help.